# Elixir: Module names with dot and nested modules - are they equivalent?

Tags: elixir

Are below codes equivalent?  As to invoke a module method, in both cases, one will use `Utilities.StringUtils.some_method(...)`

Nested modules

```
defmodule Utilities do
   defmodule StringUtils do
   end
end
```

Modules with dot in the name

```
defmodule Utilities.StringUtils do
end
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes and no. The first definition automatically defines an alias based on the module name:

```
defmodule Utilities do
  defmodule StringUtils do
  end

  # Can access the module as StringUtils
end
```

While the second:

```
defmodule Utilities.StringUtils do
  # Cannot access the module as StringUtils
end
```

Other than that, the code and module defined by both are exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, both are translated exactly to the symbol (in Erlang a module is referenced by its symbol):

`:"Elixir.Utilities.StringUtils"`

There aren't really nested modules in Erlang, it's just something Elixir simulated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -  I guess you meant `Atom`, when you referred to`Symbol`